# How to deploy an EntityFramework application in a intranet?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio, deployment

I have deployed a Windows Forms Application (Visual Studio 2013 C#) to a file share and will get my users to run the app from this file share. The app uses Entity Framework 6 and works fine from the file share but there is a delaying in loading the EntityFramework.dll during execution for the first time.

Is it possible to move just this dll from the file share to the local pc and tell the app to use it from the local pc?

Comment: are you sure the delay is because shared dll? it could be EF model initialization

Comment: Have you ruled out DNS and Proxy issues?  Both of those can introduce a 30 second delay while an invalid request times out and it can proceed with the valid request.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The problem is differently to do with initialising the EF as the application runs pretty quickly until data is being displayed in one of the forms.

Comment: I have ruled out DNS and Proxy issues as the application does work from the file share but slow when EF is being used in any of the forms. The slowness occurs once in the application and after that it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

As @tede24 stated, before trying to solve this problem, make sure EntityFramework.dll is actually your problem.

Once you make sure it is, here are the options I can think of:

**1) Use ClickOnce**

[ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh45kb66(v=vs.90).aspx) is not popular, but [it still seems to be the preferred way for deploying intranet applications](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/236235/is-clickonce-deployment-deprecated). Yes, it supports version checking and auto updates.

**2) Use some sort of XCopy installation**

You can create a batch/PowerShell to copy the application content locally from your intranet. If you want to go futher, you can even verify whether the version is the latest before launching.

**3) Try putting EntityFramework in the GAC on the client machine (not recommended)**

EntityFramework is not meant to be GACed, but you can still try to do that. I would strongly avoid it because of dependencies and update problems you might run into.